Prove classic randomized response method with coin tosses "works"
I am reading the privacy book here: https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~aaroth/Papers/privacybook.pdf, and on page 15 is the classic randomized response method:

Flip a coin with bias $p$
If heads, then respond truthfully.
If tails, then flip a second fair coin and respond “Yes” if heads and
“No” if tails.

Let's say there are $n$ users, and each user's underlying likelihood of answering yes is $r$. Then we know:
\begin{align*}
&p(yes) = p r + (1-p)/2  &&p(no) = p(1-r) + (1-p)/2.
\end{align*}
Now I want to show that this method satisfies the differential privacy definition of page 17 in privacy-book. It seems like the way to go is to say that each response over $n$ users is some $n$-bit string, and let $\mathbf{b} = [b_1,\ldots,b_n]$ be the true uncorrupted response, and let $\mathbf{\tilde{b}}$ be the corrupted string under the coin tosses. These are vertices of a boolean cube, and flipping one bit correspond to a random walk on this boolean cube. I should be able to show that the distance between the corrupted string and the original $\mathbf{b}$ is "small," that is the random walk doesn't get "too far." Chernoff bound should be used somehow, but I'm not sure how to pose the question beyond this.

What does "respond truthfully" mean?

@JairTaylor it means if I believe the answer is yes, then i respond with yes.

You never mentioned any question to respond to... Maybe it's somewhere in the link but you should make the question self-contained.

To prove that the algorithm is differentially private, you should not be looking at the difference between the original responses and the result after the coin tosses. Instead, start with two original responses that are somehow "adjacent". So in this case, suppose we have
$$\begin{eqnarray} \mathbf{b} & = & [b_1 & b_2 & \ldots & b_k & \ldots & b_n] \\
\mathbf{b'} & = & [b_1 & b_2 & \ldots & b_k' & \ldots & b_n] \end{eqnarray}$$
which are two populations of identical responses except for the $k$th response where $b_k$ answers "yes" and $b_k'$ answers "no" (or vice versa). Rather than being a likelihood, let $r$ be the actual proportion of yes answers in $\mathbf{b}$.
Then let's also define $\hat{\mathbf{b}} = \begin{bmatrix}\hat{b}_1 & \hat{b}_2 \ldots & \hat{b}_n\end{bmatrix}$ as the responses given under randomised response, so that
$$P(\hat{b}_i = yes) = 0.5 \mathbb{I}(b_i = yes) + 0.25$$
and our estimator of $r$ is $\hat{r} = \frac{1}{n}\sum \hat{b}_i$.
Then we just look at one particular outcome of the estimator, and compare the probability (or likelihood) of that outcome depending on whether it came from $\mathbf{b}$ or $\mathbf{b}'$, i.e. we compare $P(\hat{r} = a | \mathbf{b})$ and $P(\hat{r} = a | \mathbf{b}')$, and if we can find a choice of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ that satisfies the given relationship in definition 2.4 of the book across all such $\mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{b}'$ and $a$ then we say that the algorithm is $(\epsilon, \delta)$-differentially private.
For the case of $n = 1$, we only have two possible inputs and two possible outcomes of $\hat{r}$, so we see that
$$\begin{eqnarray} P(\hat{r} = 0 | b_1 = no) & = & 0.75 \\
P(\hat{r} = 0 | b_1 = yes) & = & 0.25 \\
P(\hat{r} = 1 | b_1 = no) & = & 0.25 \\
P(\hat{r} = 1 | b_1 = yes) & = & 0.75 \end{eqnarray}$$
and this satisfies the relation
$$P(\hat{r} = a | \mathbf{b}) \leq 3 P(\hat{r} = a | \mathbf{b}')$$
and thus the algorithm is $(\ln 3, 0)$-differentially private. I leave it to you to find similar bounds for $n > 1$.
